# Regex confusion - ? inside and outside of parenthesis

Tags: regex

This regex:

```
(a)?b\1c
```

does not match "bc" while this one:

```
(a?)b\1c
```

does match it. Why is this? I thought these statements are identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example `(a)?b\1c`, `\1` refers to your `(a)` group, it means you **must** have an `a` :

[image]

- `abac` will match
- `bac` will match
- `bc` won't match

In your second example `(a?)b\1c`, `\1` refers to `(a?)`, where `a` is optional :

[image]

- `abac` will match
- `bac` won't match
- `bc` will match

The back reference doesn't care of your external `?` (in the first example), **it only takes care of what is inside parenthesis**.

Comment: How did you create this pictures ?

Comment: Congratulations, you're more faster than me with beautiful pictures :)
Thanks for Regexper, I bookmark this website.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, just in the second example, I don't think "bac" will match, but "abac" will match.

Comment: @daremarkovic You're right, I totally forgot the first group ! (answer edited)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit confusing, but let's see, I will start with the second regular expression:

```
(a?)b\1c
```

When this tries to match `bc` it first tries `(a?)` but since there is no `a` in `bc`, `()` will capture the empty string `""` so when we later refer to it in the string using `\1`, `\1` will match the empty string which is always possible.

Now let's go to the second case:

```
(a)?b\1c
```

`(a)` will try to match `a` but fails, but since the entire group `(a)?` is optional, the regular expression continues, now it tries to find a `b` OK, then `\1` but `(a)?` **didn't** match anything, even the empty string so the match fails.

So the difference between the two regex is that in `(a?)` the capturing group captures an empty string which can be referenced later and matched successfully using `\1`, but `(a)?` creates an optional capturing group that didn't match anything so referencing it later using `\1` will always fails unless the group actually matched an `a`.

Answer (score 2):

In the firs version, parentheses catch `a` so `\1` returns `a`.

In the second regex, parentheses catch `a?` so `\1` returns `a?` which means "0 or 1 `a`".

As `a` is optional in the second regex, `bc` match so well the end of the second regex (`b\1c`)